# Install SharpZipLib to extract targz file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharpziplib

I download Sharpziplib, but i'm unable to install it for C#.
I didn't find the DLL. I'm lost with this Library and visualStudio, the sharpziplib contains just batchfile and source.

Anyone can help me to install it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply extract the zip-file and open the SharpZipAll.sln in you VisualStudio.
Build The ICSharpCode.SharpZLib Project and you find the Dll in the Bin-Folder.
Now you can add this Dll as a reference in your project and use it.

Here you find sample how:

https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples

Comment: thanks for your help, i open sharpzipall into visualstudio 2010 and i did Generate -> generate solution but i have lots of errors

Comment: But i have DLL into bin-folder, i will try it.

Comment: That's because the other projects have unresolved references. Lock in the Bin-Folder and you will find the DLL anyway.

Comment: Yes i find the DLL and i add this one in reference into my project and it works with the sample" to extract targz file":) thank you !